# Swiftmailer error - what does this stack trace mean?

Tags: swiftmailer

I have Swiftmailer set up to set emails via turbo-smtp, and have just started getting a 566 SMTP limit exceeded error. Is this turbo-smtp telling me I've sent too many emails, or my server's ISP, or is there something else in that error that needs to be addressed?

I'm not sending any more emails than I normally do via the day to day operation of the site.

Here's the error:

```
 [09-Feb-2016 01:34:02 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Expected response code 354 but got code "566", with message "566 SMTP limit exceeded
"' in /usr/local/lib/php/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:386
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/local/lib/php/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(281):     Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_assertResponseCode('566 SMTP limit ...', Array)
#1 /usr/local/lib/php/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php(245): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->executeCommand('DATA\r\n', Array, Array)
#2 /usr/local/lib/php/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(321): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->executeCommand('DATA\r\n', Array)
#3 /usr/local/lib/php/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(432): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_doDataCommand()
#4 /usr/local/lib/php/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(449): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_doMailTransaction(Object(Swift_Message), 'support@songboo...', Array, Array)
#5 /usr/local/lib/php/Swift/Transport/Abstra in /usr/local/lib/php/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php on line 386
```

My Swift code:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('pro.turbo-smtp.com', 25)
```

I also tried

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('pro.turbo-smtp.com', 465, 'ssl')
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 3):

Turned out I'd hit my turbo-smtp limit. I hadn't looked at it for a couple of years, so had forgotten how it all worked. Upgraded my account, and it's working again. Ideally, they'd send you a simple email saying - "hey, you've hit your email limit, and emails aren't getting out - you should upgrade to fix the problem" for us dummies.